# how does tableview cell respond to touch event? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a  `UITableView` which contains about 100 cells, each cell contains some text content,or contains a picture, or both. when taps on the picture , I  want to  call `presentModalViewController` to show a big picture from remote server.

How can I manage to realize this function? any suggestion?

Comment: Accept answer(By clicking on right tick beneath votes) if one of these helped you, this will motivate them to respond on ur questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the action to happen when tapping the picture (and none of the other elements in the row) you should use a UIButton to display the image and use the normal touch event handling of UIButton to perform the task.

If you're fine with the action happening when anything in the row is tapped, you should checkout the `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method of UITableViewDelegate.

Comment: yes, i just want to respond to  taping only on the picture ,not other element else.

Comment: then, like I said, use a UIButton with your image set as the background image to display the image in your cell.  Or you can create a custom subclass of UIImageView that will intercept touches and allow you to respond to them.  Both ways are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Simply implement the `[UITableView tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]` method and present your viewController.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  /*
   * get your object (myImagePath) here using:
   *  section: indexPath.section
   *  row: indexPath.row
   */


   MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
   [viewController setImageWithPath:myImagePath]; // I suppose that your viewController has a method to set the image.

   [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];

   [viewController release];      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath   
 {   
  YourController *objController = [[YourController alloc]         initWithNibName:@"YourController" bundle:nil];      
NSString *arrayElement = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objController animated:YES];  
[objController release];
```

}